# How to disable case sensitivity in SQL Server 2005 for object name (Table name)?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have created a new database in SQL Server 2005 and execute generated script from the old database.

In that I have a table called `MstCity`

When I try to execute the following query which has the table name in uppercase `MSTCITY`

```
SELECT City FROM MSTCITY WHERE City = 'Junagadh'
```

I get an error

> *Invalid object name 'MSTCITY'*

When I execute this `SELECT` statement it works fine

```
SELECT City FROM MstCity WHERE City = 'Junagadh'
```

In the old database both `SELECT` statement work fine. And both database are in SQL Server 2005 only.

Comment: Why do you type them in different cases? Does the case you use depend on your mood or is there something more technical behind this question?

Comment: As Query is been generated by Application.

Comment: so application generates the table name in a wrong case?

Answer (score 7):

Check the collation on the database. Then consider (but not flippantly) if it should be a CI (Case Insensitive) rather than a CS one.

Also look at the system databases. You may need to do a system rebuild to get it working right if you have built a system to migrate the database to. If your tempdb collation is different from the old box to the new one, you might find yourself with collation errors before too long.

Comment: +1 loved your "rant" on collation conflicts in SQL Server at PASS Summit :-) Absolutely hilarious :-)

Comment: That's the one at http://bit.ly/RFCollation. :)

Comment: in Collation it is showing  "Latin1_General_BIN"

Comment: Ok. BIN is the ultimate in sensitivity. Also check sys.columns to see what collation columns are using in the tables you've made.

Comment: Isn't the case sensitivity controlled by the collation of the `master` database (because that one stores the table names), not by the collation of the database being used?

Comment: No.  Table names are stored in their containing database, not in [master].  *Database* names are stored in [master], maybe that's what you meant?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As @RBarryYoung alluded, the local database's `sys.objects` is where the collation for table names has to be right, which is dependent on the local database's collation.

Comment: @RobFarley: thanks for the feedback. Actually I wasn't sure. But now I know ;)